# Edit Dynamic Values in Workflows

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to retrieve and extract specific data from incoming emails in Microsoft Dynamics CRM to use them in workflows (for update records).
The only option i can find so far while working with workflows is to get the full subject or the full body of the email. 
Is there a way to extract specific part of these two?
For example, how can i extract from the Subject the first 10 characters or how can i search the Subject or Body for specific characters or filter with REGEX?

I don't want to create a custom plugin, but the use of JavaScript would be great if it can be used to automatically get triggered without any user action.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, OOB workflow functionality does not allow you to manipulate the data within these fields. Javascript (in the context of CRM) is a client side scripting tool, so could not be run without user interaction.

I would suggest creating a Custom Workflow Activity that takes the subject and body values as parameters (from your original workflow). Then within the custom workflow you can perform string manipulation using common C# commands, and then return these values to the original workflow or update/create records within your custom workdflow.

The following URL gives a good example of creating a Custom Workflow Activity.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg334455.aspx